# Django Auth 1.11 Template does not exists 'login'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-login

I have been googling and attempting this and that and just can't get a login form to work.

I have been following this [tutorial](https://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html) which I have rebuilt a couple times in hope of catching a small error that I have missed. I also have been googling looking up errors and potential leads to to no avail.

***My issues are:*** When I run my Django app and try to reach http://localhost:9000/login/, I get two errors that toggle back and forth as I hit refresh in the browser.

**ERROR 1**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9000/login/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
login.html
Exception Location: /home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 53
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/gst/venv/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:    
['/home/vagrant/gst/tools',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/bin',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/tools/tools',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 17 Mar 2018 19:31:48 -0700

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/vagrant/gst/tools/tools/templates/login.html (Source does not exist)
```

**ERROR 2**

```
NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9000/login/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/gst/venv/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:    
['/home/vagrant/gst/tools',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/bin',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/tools/tools',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/gst/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 17 Mar 2018 19:54:07 -0700

Error during template rendering
In template /home/vagrant/gst/tools/templates/base.html, error at line 17

Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

17                                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
```

I dont know what to make of it. For **ERROR 1** that file does exist. What I have also noticed is that as i click the browsers refresh button, every few clicks the path to the login template toggles back and forth between:

*/home/vagrant/gst/tools/tools/templates/login.html*

and

*/home/vagrant/gst/tools/templates/login.html*

When the correct path is loaded I then get the **ERROR 2** which also baffles me and I dont beleive i have an issue with line 17 as error states. I have confirmed the class tag exists in the css static files. I have tried to set all files to full permissions 777 so i have ruled out a permissions issue.

Help would be greatly appreciated. My configs are below:

```
.
├── authauth
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── home.html
│   └── login.html
└── tools
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

***tools.settings.py*** *(lines only worth noting, I hope)*

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tools.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

***tools/urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views
from authauth.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('authauth.urls')),
    url(r'^login/?$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
]
```

***authauth/views.py***

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")
```

***authauth/urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

***authauth/forms.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))
```

**templates/base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Auth Demo</title>
                <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
                <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rocky Balbo</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Account
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="/home">home</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>

                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}


                    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
                    <script src = "{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src = "{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        {% block javascript %}
        {% endblock %}


            </body>
        </html>
```

**templates/home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>You are on your Dashboard</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/login.html**

{

```
% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}

<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}

<p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url login %}">
{% csrf_token %}

                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </p>
                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <center>
                                <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="login" />
                            </center>
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}


<script>
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
$("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").css("display","none");
{% endif %}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks parth patil for your reply. All that did was add an extra directory to my errors. I did see same coments you made in other post regarding the template folder structure so I am sure there is validity. ^__^

I found a solution. I think at least a part of my solution was that this was missing from my **urls.py** file:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
```

I rebuilt my app following this [page](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

Very frustrating as (just like the other tutorial) what he wrote did not a)work and b) match his code in github. Anyways I am rambling, login is fully working now just make sure you are using a variance of this code in [here](https://github.com/sibtc/simple-django-login)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a folder inside templates named tools and keep all your templates inside that folder 
This is method suggested in django documentation 
Also dont forget to change the path to tools/login.html